# Resolve JSP EL within JSP EL

Tags: jsp, dom, el

I have a bean variable say `url` that gets its value from db and it can also have a dynamic argument passed to it in db. Say if a base url is `https://test.com/myapp.action` it can also be as `https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=${user.userId}` (with dynamic argument passed) where `user.userId` is another bean variable now this `url` bean variable is placed in a jsp like this

```
<a href="${url}"></a>
```

The problem is that it is resolving in DOM as `https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=${user.userId}` but I want it to be resolved as `https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=myuser` if `user.userId="myuser"` in server session.

Comment: please provide more info. What is allowed and what is not? what could be changed and what not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do some processing of the url in your servlet, and resolve the embedded expression.
I used a JSP just for demonstration.
This is not a general solution. It serves only this case. It will not work with multiple or cascaded EL/placeholder in other ways.

What the code do, is basically

- split the url in parts by delimiters `${` and `}`,
- resolve the embedded EL/placeholder
- generate the new url by concatenation

**The Code:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>JSP EL resolver</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
session.setAttribute("user.userId", "myuser");
pageContext.setAttribute("url", "https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=${user.userId}");
%>

url before preparation: <a href="${url}">${url}</a><br>

<%
String url = (String) pageContext.getAttribute("url");
String[] parts = url.split("\\$\\{|\\}");

String newUrl = parts[0];
String userEL = parts[1];

String sessionUser = session.getAttribute(userEL).toString();

pageContext.setAttribute("url", newUrl + sessionUser);
%>

url after preparation: <a href="${url}">${url}</a><br>

</body>
</html>
```

**The Output:**

```
url before preparation: https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=${user.userId}
url after preparation: https://test.com/myapp.action?userid=myuser
```

This is a solution, but a dirty one.

**Better solution will be:**

- Storing only the base path in DB or Property-File
- Creating some classes which append the parameters (names and values)

**The Benefits will be:**

- less repetition,
- less DB / Disk storage will be wasted,
- easy to maintain
- easy to change the base url

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But in my case i cant add proceding in servlet. This is all part of a template code and o just have to find a way to resolve cascade EL resolution

Comment: What about HttpSessionAttributeListener? You can move the EL-resolver-code there. When attributeAdded() or attributeReplaced(). is triggered, adapt the value.